# QT Creator can't use CMake or QMake in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt-creator

I am trying to do a course task with QT Creator and we are practicing organizing the programs in sperate classes files and such. I am a beginner and I suppose I just need to add classes to the project to do this. But that's not my problem as that could be found on the internet if I don't know how to do it.

The problem is how to get started with the tool kits, I choose New project and click on QMake and then I can't click Next past that. With Cmake the project is created but CMake returns code 1.

I installed both 32 bit and 64 bit. I'm like WTH with this, a regular beginner user should be able to start with this IDE not just throw a bunch of GUI options that don't work.

How do you get from 0 to compiling C++ classes in QT Creator?

Here are the maintainer screenshots

[01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hev5M.png)

[02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qlD1.png)

Comment: Have you read [the manual](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html)? If so, please tell us 1) what you installed (Qt and compiler version) 2) what errors you get from QMake and CMake. As a beginner I would seriously recommend just getting Visual Studio Community or switching to Linux.

Comment: @Botje, I do not agree with that: _As a beginner I would seriously recommend just getting Visual Studio Community or switching to Linux._ For a beginner the best option would be the Qt Creator as a dedicated IDE, where everything is automatically set-up. The OP is probably missing a compiler.

Comment: I admit that getting a compiler toolkit configured is about as hard as getting your first Qt project off the ground in VS. However, OP has not specifically stated that they are trying to use Qt, only "compiling C++ classes". You get that out of the box with VS, along with built-in CMake support once they decide to make the leap.

Comment: @Botje, _OP has not specifically stated that they are trying to use Qt_ I assumed that from the tag - [qt]. For a vanilla c++ VS is indeed the way to go.

Comment: I'm just learning C++ and I intend to use QT Creator for the Qt development. I installed MinGW 32 and 64, I added the bin folder to the path so I can use the command as if in Linux. But I want to get Qt creator running. I'll add a pic of the Maintainer.

Comment: I got it, instead of adding a kit I modified the Desktop kit because it wasn't pointing to the compiler. Finally, I picked CMake for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the **Desktop** kit to point to the same compiler for **C and C++**, Select *Tools > Options > Kits*

And choose **CMake** for the plain console project.